# Curvature for parabola

Tags: calculus, limits, curvature

About another method of finding the radius of curvature, given by Norman J. Wildberger (a person which sometimes seems to be a "crank"):

The radius of a circle due to an inscribed triangle $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a,b,c$ is $R=\dfrac{abc}{4S_\triangle}$ .

He uses this to find the radius of curvature formula of $y=x^2$ .

But he uses the cross product for the area:
$$\begin{align}
&A(p,p^2)\ ,\ B(q,q^2)\ ,\ C(r,r^2)\\\\
a^2&=(p-q)^2\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\\b^2&=(q-r)^2\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\\c^2&=(r-p)^2\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]\\\\
\vec A-\vec C&=\binom{p-r}{p^2-r^2}\ ,\ \vec B-\vec C=\binom{q-r}{q^2-r^2}\\\\
S_\triangle&=\frac{\Big|(\vec A-\vec C)\times(\vec B-\vec C)\Big|}{2}\\
&=\frac{\Big|(p-r)(q^2-r^2)-(p^2-r^2)(q-r)\Big|}{2}\\
&=\frac{\Big|(p-r)(q-r)(q+r)-(p-r)(p+r)(q-r)\Big|}{2}\\
&=\frac{\Big|(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)\Big|}{2}\end{align}$$
Now
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{p,q,r\to t}r&=\lim_{p,q,r\to t}\frac{\sqrt{(p-q)^2(q-r)^2(r-p)^2\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{4\dfrac{\bigl|(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)\bigr|}{2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{p,q,r\to t}\frac{\bigl|(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)\bigr|\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{2\bigl|(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)\bigr|}\\\\
&=\lim_{p,q,r\to t}\frac{\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{(1+4t^2)^3}}{2}
\end{align}$$
But when I tried using Heron's formula for the area and plugging it in, this did not work and I did not get any cancellation terms:
$$R=\frac{abc}{4\dfrac{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}}{4}}$$
Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

$
\begin{align}
&A(p,p^2)\ ,\ B(q,q^2)\ ,\ C(r,r^2)\\\\
a^2&=(p-q)^2\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\\b^2&=(q-r)^2\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\\c^2&=(r-p)^2\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]\\\\
\end{align}
$

I used this version to substitute in the denominator

$a^2= \left(p^2-q^2\right)^2+(p-q)^2,\\b^2= \left(q^2-r^2\right)^2+(q-r)^2,\\c^2= \left(r^2-p^2\right)^2+(r-p)^2$

$$R=\frac{abc}{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}}=\frac{abc}{\sqrt{-a^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 - b^4 + 2 a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 - c^4}}$$

$$R=\frac{|p-q||q-r||r-p|\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{\sqrt{den}}$$

where $den = 2 \left(\left(p^2-q^2\right)^2+(p-q)^2\right) \left(\left(r^2-p^2\right)^2+(r-p)^2+\left(q^2-r^2\right)^2+(q-r)^2\right)-\left(-\left(r^2-p^2\right)^2-(r-p)^2+\left(q^2-r^2\right)^2+(q-r)^2\right)^2-\left(\left(p^2-q^2\right)^2+(p-q)^2\right)^2\quad(*)$

$$R=\frac{|p-q||q-r||r-p|\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{\sqrt{4 (p-q)^2 (p-r)^2 (q-r)^2}}$$

$$R=\frac{|p-q||q-r||r-p|\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{2 |p-q| |p-r||q-r|}$$

$$R=\frac{\sqrt{\bigl[1+(p+q)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(q+r)^2\bigr]\bigl[1+(r+p)^2\bigr]}}{2}$$

and the limit obviously gives the same result

$(*)$ the factorization was made with the help of *Mathematica*

Hope this can help

Comment: What is $den$ ?

Comment: $den$ is the very long denominator I had to write apart because there was no room under the fraction :)

Comment: Please don't tell me you got to the $4(p-q)^2(q-r)^2(r-p)^2$ by opening all that.

Comment: Yes, of course. With a little help from *Mathematica*. Your "crank" Norman chose a much shorter way, but the result must be the same: think about it :)

Comment: No denial.

Another question: How to find the curvature vector?

Comment: Here you can find formulas for parametrized parabola $(t,\;t^2)$ Should be $$\kappa =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(4 t^2+1\right)^3}}$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I meant the direction vector $\vec R$ of the curvature's radius $R$.

Comment: It is the normal vector at $(t,t^2)$. If the tangent vector is $\vec T=(1,2t)$ the vector $\vec R=(a,b)$ must satisfy $\vec T\cdot \vec R=0$ and $|\vec R|=\dfrac{\sqrt{(4t^2+1)^3}}{2}$ therefore we have the system $$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+2 b t=0 \\
 a^2+b^2=\frac{1}{4} \left(4 t^2+1\right)^2 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
The "good" solution is $$\vec R=\left(-t \sqrt{4 t^2+1}, \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 t^2+1}\right)$$ which is toward the simmetry axis of the parabola

Comment: I think the vector is wrong, and you meant $a^2+b^2=\dfrac{(4a^2+1)^3}{4}$. But why "good" solution?

Comment: Yes, of course it is $a^2+b^2=\dfrac{1}{4} \left(4 t^2+1\right)^3$ and the vector is $-4 t^3-t, \dfrac{1}{2} \left(4 t^2+1\right)$ the other solution is $4 t^3+t, \dfrac{1}{2} \left(-4 t^2-1\right)$ and is the other perpendicular vector which goes outside the parabola look here https://imgur.com/m9TgwDF

Comment: I asked in another place and the answer was $\vec r=\vec f+r\vec n$ where $\vec n\perp\vec f'$ - but this is possible in 2 different ways. Isn't $\vec n$ suppose to be unique?